# Design Library Android

Tags: android, android-design-library, android-appbarlayout

I'm using Android Design Library components, and I would like to have an image behind my `ToolBar` and `TabLayout`. The image must be cropped and not fit to the size. I'm actually setting my image as `android:background="@drawable/AppBarBg"` in `AppBarLayout` which doesn't crop (of course) my image. How can I crop my background image ?

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@drawable/AppBarBg"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        style="@style/ToolBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

AppBarLayout is basically just a LinearLayout so setting a background will strech it...

I think that you're looking for CollapsingToolbarLayout...
Your layout structure should be like this:

> AppBarLayout
>   CollapsingToolbarLayout
>   ImageView (this is the background which you want to centerCrop)
>   ToolBar
>   TabLayout
>   etc...

check it out here: [CollapsingToolbarLayout and TabLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30625979/collapsingtoolbarlayout-and-tablayout)

Comment: thanks I actually tried with this but first I don't want to collapse anything and playing with the different attributes it replaced my image by a color. 
I will try more with it